# Knockout and AJAX post request PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, knockout.js, laravel

I am attempting to get our knockout form to submit to a php script and am getting undefinedIndex errors. I am pretty sure it is the way we are sending the data over in our ajax function.

Here is the ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '/orders/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: {payload:ko.toJSON(allModel)},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

Here is the PHP (we use laravel)

```
 return json_decode($_POST["payload"]);
```

Comment: You have 2 data fields.

Comment: Sorry. That just displays here. One is commented out.

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify({payload:ko.toJSON(allModel)}),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pete is correct.  You need to use just one data field.  If you want a variable, define it before the $.ajax post

```
var dataPayload = ko.toJSON(allModel);
$.ajax({
    url: '/orders/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: {payload: dataPayload},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I receive a 500 Internal server error. 

So this is what is being sent in POST from the console:
payload=%5B%7B%22serviceName%22%3A%223%22%2C%22serviceQuantity%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%22bec09c54-d967-f376-703c-4bfd3319b7cb%22%5D

The response is Notice: Undefined index: payload

Comment: @ipengineer This is a server-side issue, not a javascript/jquery/ajax issue.  Are you taking the data parameters in your service and looping through the results or trying to treat it like an array?

Comment: I think I am just treating it as an object. I am just doing return json_decode($_POST['payload']);

Comment: @ipengineer Is that the expected payload for your form?  Perhaps the ko.ToJSON does some unexpected things.  Instead, can you try JSON.stringify(allModel); and see it that works?

Comment: I think that was part of the problem. The issue is now how to get all of the objects out.. This is what the post request looks like:

[{"serviceName":"2","serviceQuantity":"4"},{"serviceName":"3","serviceQuantity":"2"},{"hardwareName":"1","hardwareQuantity":"6","hardwareBYOD":""}]

Im assuming I need to somehow decode it and then do a foreach.

Comment: @ipengineer Yup, you've got it.  For whatever reason the ko.toJSON did a poor encoding.  Simply decode, then iterate through your objects with a foreach loop and you should be good.